# Armazenar dados de JSON no amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-aws

Há alguma maneira de salvar dados de um JSON online em um banco amazon dinamicamente? Estou tentando consumir os dados de um site porém não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor o seu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o Aws Lambda para consumir o Json e jogar para o RDS de tempos em tempos.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html